# How to combine multiple typed Observables into one

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array of Observables like this (Typescript):

```
let observables: Observable<string | string[]>[] = ...
```

As you can see, the observables in this array can emit (at once) either a single string or an array of string. Each of this observables can emit values (string or array of strings) more then once.

I'd like to have a resulting observable of this type:

```
let resultObservable: Observable<string> = observables.operator(...)
```

1.) Ho to do this? What operator should I use?
2.) What operator should I use, when I'd like to have a resulting observable which emits only one value, which is an array of strings:

```
let resultObservable: Observable<string[]> = observable.operator(...)
```

**Edit**: I prepared a plnkr in order to showcase the issue: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GLwtqIhPiyH3ztaw

Comment: So which one you want? `string` or `string[]`?

Comment: Hi @Andy why have you deleted my valid response?

Answer (score 0):

Only string value

```
arrayOrNot.flatMap(data=>data.isArray()?
Observable.from(data):Observable.of(data)).subscribe()
```

With only array of string that really depends when you complete the emission with what criteria

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it possible for you to showcase this by using the prepared plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GLwtqIhPiyH3ztaw ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe with reduce and map ?

[example on plnkr.co](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/jNXS1mBvkd3REF2J)